# React toggle view functionality in the parent via child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, conditional-rendering

I am trying to toggle view between list of meals and meal details. I have placed a button in the child component *Meal.js* to the *Meals.js* which is meant to be the list and the details view.

Can you please help me fix this issue. Seems like its not working even with the conditional rendering method I've used in the code below.

Meal.js

```
import { useState } from 'react'

import './Meal.css'

const Meal = (props) => {

  const [isToggled, setIsToggled] = useState(false);

  const sendIdHandler = () => {
    if (isToggled === true) {
      setIsToggled(false);
    }
    else {
      setIsToggled(true);
    }
    props.onSaveIdHandler(props.id, isToggled)
  }

  return (
    <div
      className='meal'
      onClick={sendIdHandler}
    >
      {props.label}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Meal;
```

Meals.js

```
import Meal from './Meal/Meal'


const Meals = (props) => {

  let toggleCondition = false;

  const saveIdHandler = (data, isToggled) => {
    toggleCondition = isToggled;
    const mealDetails = props.mealsMenuData.findIndex(i =>
      i.id === data
    )
    console.log(mealDetails, toggleCondition)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {toggleCondition === false &&
        props.mealsMenuData.map(item =>
          <Meal
            key={item.id}
            id={item.id}
            label={item.label}
            onSaveIdHandler={saveIdHandler}
          />
        )
      }
      {toggleCondition === true &&
        <div>Horray!</div>
      }
    </div>
  );
}

export default Meals;
```

**UPDATE**

Finally figured how to do this properly. I put the condition true/false useState in the parent instead and have Meal.js only send the id I need to view the item

Code is below..

Meals.js

```
import { useState } from 'react'

import Meal from './Meal/Meal'
import MealDetails from './MealDetails/MealDetails'


const Meals = (props) => {

  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const [mealId, setMealId] = useState(0);

  const saveIdHandler = (data) => {
    setShow(true);

    setMealId(props.mealsMenuData.findIndex(i =>
      i.id === data)
    )
    console.log(props.mealsMenuData[mealId].ingridients)
  }

  const backHandler = () => {
    setShow(false)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {show === false &&
        props.mealsMenuData.map(item =>
          <Meal
            key={item.id}
            id={item.id}
            label={item.label}
            onSaveIdHandler={saveIdHandler}
          />
        )
      }
      {show === true &&
        <div>
          <MealDetails data={props.mealsMenuData[mealId]} />
          <button onClick={backHandler}>Back</button>
        </div>
      }
    </div>
  );
}

export default Meals;
```

Meal.js

```
import './Meal.css'

const Meal = (props) => {

  const sendIdHandler = () => {
    props.onSaveIdHandler(props.id)
  }

  return (
    <div
      className='meal'
      onClick={sendIdHandler}
    >
      {props.label}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Meal;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem in `sendIdHandler`: You can update like this:

```
const sendIdHandler = () => {
    const newIsToggled = !isToggled;
    setIsToggled(newIsToggled)
    props.onSaveIdHandler(props.id, newIsToggled)
  }
```